# dataflow custom container not used?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to run a dataflow pipeline with a custom container -- I want to supply all of my pipeline's python dependencies this way vs pip installing them when the pipeline starts.

I'm starting the pipeline like this:

```
python main.py \
  --setup_file ./setup.py   \
  --job_name test  \
  --runner DataflowRunner   \
  --region us-central1   \
  --temp_location gs://<mybucket>/temp   \
  --max_num_workers 5   \
  --subnetwork regions/us-central1/subnetworks/default \
  --no_use_public_ips   \
  --experiments=beam_fn_api,use_runner_v2   \
  --sdk_container_image=gcr.io/path/to/custom_runner
```

The job is submitted successfully, and the first worker VM does start. However, when the VM starts to try to run my pipeline, **I get an error about one of the dependencies not being found**. why?

- Yes, the container **does** contain the (the right version of the) dependency. I verified by pulling the custom container locally, starting /bin/bash in the container and running `pip list`
- I have verified that my local local configuration also has the same dependencies and versions.
- I have verified that the dataflow and compute engine (b/c I'm not sure which) default service accounts have access to my gcr.io repository
- I have verified that `gcr.io/path/to/custom_runner` actually exists in gcr.io  :)
- I have verified that I am using Apache Beam 2.34.0 locally and in the custom container. Any place else to check?

  ```
  #local venv
  (test) $ pip list|grep beam
  apache-beam                     2.34.0

  #custom container
  (test) $ docker run -it --rm --entrypoint /bin/bash gcr.io/path/to/custom_runner
  root@008c0bc581d0:/# pip list|grep beam
  apache-beam                     2.34.0
  ```

I can see NOTHING in any logs that indicates that the custom container is being pull/instantiated. I can ssh to the worker VM, where I get a hint that it's *not* being used by tailing all the container logs on the VM. I also notice that my image is never listed in docker images. The most telling hint I do have is:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
7ff3f8d3e979   gcr.io/cloud-dataflow/v1beta3/python38   "/opt/google/dataflo…"   6 seconds ago        Up 5 seconds                  k8s_python_df-vcf-to-bigque
ry-12130811-agjj-harness-9bfq_default_452222efa0209ab78bfd57c9873461e6_0
```

which looks like the default container instead.

My questions:

1. How can I actually verify which container the pipeline is being started in? Should I be able to see the image name in the logs?
2. Assuming I can find direct evidence of the wrong (default) container being used, why is the specified custom container not being tried/used instead?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I'm at fault (surprise!) I had an ArgParse (https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) class that was eating the `--sdk_container_image` flag